# Is this an acceptable malloc example?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

Is the following code acceptable. That is, is this the right way to do a malloc?

This is the minimal code that I could get to work for my situation. I think it's 'the right way to do it' but I am super-new to C and don't have much of a clue overall. I read several related SO posts but none seem to exactly match this situation. Comments?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// example of calling a function that creates a dynamically sized array and
// returns it to a caller that doesn't know or care about the size of the array

char* return_char_array(){
     // for the sake of the example, we determined the size to be 100
     char *f=malloc(100*sizeof(char));
     // stick something in the first couple of elements for test purposes
     *f=65;
     *(f+1)=66;
     return f;
}

int main(){
    // we want this function to remain ignorant of the size or other workings 
    // of the array, so, no '[]' or 'malloc'
    char *wipc = return_char_array();
    // well i guess it cares a little, because we assume there are at least 2 elements...
    printf("%c,%c\n",*(wipc),*(wipc+1));
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If this is homework add the homework tag

Comment: 'Is this the right way to accomplish calling a function that creates and returns a dynamically sized array'?

Comment: It's not literally homework in the sense that I'm not taking a course or anything like that.

Comment: Your comment says `no '[]'`, but you use `*(wipc+1)`, which is exactly the same as `wipc[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is a bad idea and doesn't make much sense. The code that is allocating the memory needs to be responsible for freeing it, or you will have a great potential for memory leaks.

Typically you would write algorithms like this:

```
// caller.c

#include "stuff.h"  // the code uses the code module "stuff"

void caller (void)
{
  int* array = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

  do_stuff(array, N);

  free(array);
}
```

_

```
// stuff.h

void do_stuff (int* array, int size);
```

_

```
// stuff.c

#include "stuff.h"

void do_stuff (int* array, int size)
{
  ...
}
```

With this program design, "do_stuff()" doesn't need to care about memory allocation, it just executes its algorithm. Nor does anyone have to worry about memory leaks, because allocation and freeing is done from the same place.

Also, with this design, do_stuff() will work just as fine with statically allocated memory (simple arrays).

This design is pretty much the norm in C. The whole Windows API uses this design, as one example.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but returning an object obtained by `malloc` is not bad style. In fact it's one of the only real uses of `malloc` except for working with data that's too large to reliably keep on the stack. The whole point of `malloc` is creating objects of dynamic storage duration; in your usage, it's equivalent to an object of automatic storage duration except that it can be bigger than would fit on the stack.

Comment: @R.. If you find yourself returning non-constant pointers to dynamic memory outside the module where it was allocated, then that is bad style, not only because of the potential for memory leaks but also because it breaks encapsulation and good object-oriented design. Why should someone else be responsible for cleaning up your trash? This answer isn't taken out of the blue, I have plenty of experience of debugging crappily written programs in search of memory leaks. In 9 out of 10 cases, the memory leaks come from bad program design.

Comment: No, it doesn't break object-oriented design; it's *absolutely necessary* to object oriented design. An object-oriented library will have functions of the form `myobject *myobject_create(...);` and `void myobject_destroy(myobject *);`

Comment: @R.. If `myobject` is an opaque (incomplete) type I would agree. Or if it was a const pointer. If it is not either of those two, it is bad design and breaks oo.

Comment: Opaqueness has nothing to do with the validity of returning pointers to allocated objects; it's only relevant to other object-oriented principles that might or might not be relevant to the library/program in question. In OP's code, a standard C string is a perfectly reasonable type of object to be dealing with that need not be treated as opaque, and for which it may be useful to have dynamic storage duration. The only bug is that OP forgot to free it (and probably forgot to document that the function returns a newly allocated object).

Comment: By the way, returning a `const`-qualified pointer to a newly allocated object is almost always wrong. It means (if you actually honor the `const`-ness) you're never allowed to free it.

Comment: @R.. In an oo program, the module itself would keep track of the dynamic memory internally, and free it from a delete function. The const pointer isn't to be used for freeing, because _the caller is not responsible to clean up the mess caused by your code module_. A pointer to an opaque type need not be const, because the caller can't actually alter it. Even though using const for that would be good style.

Comment: I'm not talking about memory allocated internally for use by the object, but the *object itself*. This cannot be tracked internally unless you plan on doing some hideous misdesign with global state. Yes, if the object is opaque then the caller cannot directly free it, but the caller will pass the pointer back to `myobject_free` or similar to free it, and this function in turn needs a non-const pointer to free. So if you use `const`-qualified pointers, the `myobject_free` function will have to cast away the const, which although legal is just horribly wrong.

Comment: @R.. It is a fairly easy task to write an internal memory pool inside the class, no matter whether the opaque objects are allocated dynamically or statically.

Comment: Again we're talking about where the object itself lives versus where it stores additional memory/objects it needs for its own internal use. If the object it obtained by an allocator function (the only way for it to really be opaque in C), then this allocator function must return memory obtained by `malloc` without freeing it.

Answer (score 4):

> Comments?

Use `f[0]` instead of `*f` and `f[1]` instead of `*(f + 1)`. Same goes for `wipc`. Don't forget to call `free`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's OK in this situation.
But remember to free the memory allocated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage whatsoever for any function to not know the size of an array it's working with. The comment requires explanation.

Comment: Indeed, 'main' needs to know the size of the thing that 'return_char_array' created; what i meant was, 'main' shouldn't need to know about it in advance. It should let 'return_char_array' create whatever sized array it needs, as opposed to 'main' doing the malloc itself or specifying a fixed array size. (I hope I'm making sense).

Comment: Ok, but this only works for this very trivial example. I'd have written so that `return_char_array` takes a parameter that specifies the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Agreed. So that parameter would be an int pointer, and the function would still return the malloc'd pointer like it does now, correct?

Comment: Just an int: `char* return_char_array(int elements)`, it would behave the same

Answer (score 0):

On the very first sight i acknowledge that you dont free() your malloced space, wich is bad (Memory-Leak). Thats the only real "fault" i can see. But, if you want more insight in form of a Code-Review you might post it on the Stackexchange Site "Code-Review", as this Site is more in solving actual problems and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is really minimal code.
I would rather to put the extra mark bytes at the end of the buffer, and remember to add the extra 2 bytes to the buffer length when malloc

Those 2 bytes are reserved for internal usage, and should not be exposed to user.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments,

1)Pl. do proper error handling. What happens if malloc fails?

```
char *f=malloc(100*sizeof(char))
if (NULL == f)
{   
   //Take actions ..Exit with error or return NULL..
}
```

2)Pl. avoid hardcoded values like 100 ( may have a #define MAX 100)

3)Pl. make sure to free the memory properly.